# Many to many association form with collection_check_boxes results in validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: Course, Category, and Categorisation.

```
# course.rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorisations, foreign_key: "course_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, through: :categorisations  
end

#category.rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :categorisations, foreign_key: "category_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :courses, through: :categorisations
end

# categorisation.rb
class Categorisation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :category

  validates :course_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

Course controller has the following params:

```
def course_params
  params.require(:course).permit(:name, :prerequisite, :description,
                                 :user_id, :category_ids => [])
end
```

I'm trying to build the association via the Course form:

```
<%= form_for @course do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :prerequisite %>
  <%= f.text_field :prerequisite, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :category_ids, "Category" %>
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name, 
                        {}, { multiple: true, class: 'form-control'} %>

  <%= f.submit "Create a new course", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

However when I click submit I get the validation error:

> Categorisations is invalid

I'm unsure why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the presence validation on `:course_id` will fix the issue

```
class Categorisation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :category

  # validates :course_id, presence: true
  validates :category_id, presence: true
end
```

**Problem:**

Course is not saved but due to through association when you associate category with course rails first tries to save `categorisation` but course_id is not available yet

And this is the reason presence validation fails for course_id

**Solution**

Removing the validation is just a workaround the actual solution will be something interesting

> **NOTE:** Even I am facing the similar issue a few days back. we have removed validation for now. I will be interested in any better solution

Answer (score 1):

You're not able to save any entity that relates to Categorization in database because of `presence: true` action. Firstly, I think it's a better idea to validate `:category_id` in the `schema.rb` by `category_id null: false`. And secondly, are you sure you need the Categorization model? My suggestion is to think of putting a `categorizationable.rb` file in your `yourApp/app/models/concerns` folder and after that using its functionality in the existing models. You can read more about concerns [here](https://gist.github.com/dhh/1014971). This technique is really powerful when your models need refactoring.